# How can I delete an answer of mine through the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

There doesn't appear to be an option to delete my answer. Can I not do that through the app?

[image: Image options]

Comment: Not yet supported.

Comment: That's a slightly different question but the answer applies to both.

Answer (score -2):

> That's a slightly different question but the answer applies to both

Your direct answer, then, is "You cannot do this".

Which means you need a feature request. As one already exist for the exact same thing, rather than create a new one we dupe this question to the current one. Even though this is a support request, this question becomes a relevant signpost with searchable keywords so others might find it, and the dupe link sends them to the feature request.

Whether it's implemented or not is another matter, but collating everything to one area makes it easier to track etc.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes folks. Always appreciated when just trying to pass along some friendly and helpful info to a fellow user. I never expected any upvotes, but 2 downvotes? I hope you have a lovely day both of you!

Comment: To be honest it was me who downvoted you because this answer adds nothing but "go to the feature request", which was proposed as duplicate already. This could have been a comment instead.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Providing "useful" friendly advice and info in an answer which *answers the question* doesn't warrant a downvote. As it answers the question, how can this "answer" be a "comment instead"? This question will likely stay as a signpost to the dupe, so an answer answering the question and explaining why a [support] question is duped as a [feature-request] seems prudent and completes the thread as a good signpost. People often complain and get confused about dupes, not understanding the principles behind them. I would say it's perhaps a little "nose in the rule book".

Comment: @PatrickHofman With that said, I'm just arguing why **I** feel it didn't warrant a downvote, and fully respect your opinion in why you downvoted :) (I'm sure others could debate some of my downvote reasons etc)